# How to make Eclipse Kepler open jee servlets in internal web browser automatically when you deploy application?

Tags: eclipse, servlets, browser

I used to have Eclipse Luna before, but I had to replace it with Kepler.
In Luna then I was choosing particular servlet and then I was pressing on "Run on Server" it was opening the response internal browser in eclipse. It was very convenient, so I did not have to manually type the URL in browser.
But in Eclipse Kepler it does not do so, and I couldn't find a way to do it.
Please advise my how to solve this small issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to open in J2EE perspective, as most of version there is option in preference once you open in J2EE. But I am not seeing it in Kepler. I just downloaded the kepler to check option.

Comment: I don't see option to create dynamic web project also.

Comment: Actually I recently found out that it runs in internal browser the projects that you create like: Dynamic Web Project. But it does not work if you create Maven project.

Comment: I do not know, guys, which version of Eclipse are you using, but I use and I can create Dynamic Web Project: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Comment: I use eclipse helios now and I have used many eclipse versoin ,  there i know option for selecting browser is in top menu window --> browser --> internet explorer.